# asynchronous node.js concepts with IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
var net = require ('net'),
local_port = 8000,
local_ip = '127.0.0.1',
remote_port = 80,
remote_ip = 'xxx.xx.xx.x',

server = net.createServer (function (socket){
  var serviceSocket = new net.Socket ();
  serviceSocket.connect (parseInt (remote_port), remote_ip, function () {
    socket.on ('data', function (msg){
      serviceSocket.write (msg);
    });
  });
}).listen (local_port, local_ip);
```

There is SERVER, which runs this code, and CLIENT, which connects to SERVER and sends two blocks of data one after another, D1 and then D2.

Is it true, that D2 will always arrive before D1 to *remote_ip*?

**Wouldn't a case like this be possible:**

Let's say CLIENT sends D1 of size **x** asynchronously, and then D2 of size **y**, where y is much smaller than x, wouldn't then `socket.on('data'...)` fire first with the reception of D2 on its 'data' listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.createServer` and `net.Socket` both create TCP sockets.

This has a few implications:

1. Data you write first will be received first.
2. Boundaries are *not* fixed, that is a single `write` on one side may be split into multiple `data` events on the receiving side, or vise versa multiple `write` calls may become a single `data` event. The only guarantee is that the data will remain in the same order you write it.

If you're interested in unordered (and unreliable) data you could look at node's `dgram` module  http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html which creates UDP sockets, but for most cases you want TCP.